# I'm so frustrated with uv image/editor. I can't get my decal to show in render after editing the decal in gimp

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv-image-editor

All I did was edit the texture in GIMP and now the decal texture won't show in my render.  I tried renaming... no go.  I spent half a day now trying to get it back.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my blend....

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T8I2Y8ZTdtWhvcV6k1s5m96fAVsQl4Nt

EDIT:  I'm an idiot.  I was working on an alternate node setup in the node editor that wasn't connected to a material output.  I didn't realize until I zoomed out and saw the real node setup.  It works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to show by simplifying the material and making sure I had a material output node. The use of the alpha here is a little confusing, but I suppose if you can get one showing and then use the alpha to set a separate shader of another color then you might work it out.[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I am the biggest idiot.  I just realized I had an alternate node set up off screen but the one I was editing wasn't connected to material output.  Seeing your post made me go look for the material output so thanks for that.

Comment: If you zoom out you will see the other node setup.  It is working as expected now.

Comment: Been there, done that, and have the t-shirt and the hat. Don't worry, this kind of thing still serves to show others to not panic and look for a simple, logical solution if things just don't make sense :D